# Error in setting up PostgreSQL in Kubernates

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to setup postgres in my Kubernates enabled Docker Desktop. I pulled images 'postgres:latest' and 'dpage/pgadmin4:latest' from Docker Hub. Below are my yaml files. Everything starts perfectly. I can open the pgAdmin page from Chrome. The creds i have given in the yaml file are not logging me in.
What is causing this issue?

postgres Db:-

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-config
  labels:
    app: postgres
data:
  POSTGRES_DB: app
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
    app: postgres
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi


---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: postgres:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-config
        volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: app
      volumes:
        - name: app
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
   - port: 5432
  selector:
   app: postgres
```

pgAdmin :-

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: pgadmin-config
  labels:
    app: pgadmin4
data:
  PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ap@a.com
  PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: posdt

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pgadmin4
  labels:
    app: pgadmin4
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pgadmin4
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pgadmin4
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pgadmin4
        image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: pgadmin-config
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: pgadmin4
  labels:
    app: pgadmin4
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
   - port: 80
  selector:
   app: pgadmin4
```

Comment: All I did was removed `imagePullPolicy: Never` and it works. (tested on minikube)

Answer (score 0):

I just deployed and was able to connect the database. see below

```
postgres-7cb54957dd-qkfd4   1/1     Running             0          13s
# kubectl exec -it postgres-7cb54957dd-qkfd4 sh
# psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -q -d app -c 'SELECT 1'
 ?column?
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

used below YAML with slight modifications

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-config
  labels:
    app: postgres
data:
  POSTGRES_DB: app
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: postgres:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-config
        volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: app
      volumes:
        - name: app
          emptyDir: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
   - port: 5432
  selector:
   app: postgres
```

Comment: Thanks I'm able to connect to the database using psql. The pgAdmin login page is loading but the login creads are not working. What can be the issue? Yaml file attached.